# float data type python and sqlit3

Tags: python, sqlite

I have 20 million rows of data in maybe 40 sqlite3 databases.  they are all the same:  unix time stamp and several columns of numbers.  the numbers are all type [float].  (the time stamp is [str])
The tables were made by me and defined as REAL.  Sometimes I have trouble and I think it is related to the data type. I do not seem to be able to change it.

I ask for the type right out of the database and it gives me [float]

Sometimes I have no problems.  But this little error code is pretty representative.

```
for row in c.fetchmany(50):
    new_var = int(row[0])
    print ("test", type(new_var))
```

error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/mrphy/Desktop/mu only/datatypes 01.py", line 45, in <module>
    new_var = int(row[0])
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'NoneType'
```

I calculate averages etc at time intervals.  I think it freezes when it can find no numbers.  But a filter does not seem to work.

Comment: The traceback indicates that whatever the column is at `row[0]` can be `None` (`NULL`), and your code doing `int(None)` will produce this problem. Should your column have a `NOT NULL` constraint on it? Otherwise, you will need to add checking to make sure you're not trying to process null data.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas for reading database instead.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_sql_query("Your query here", con) #con is your db connection
```

Then replace all null values (no numbers) and perform similar pandas operation and then takes avg of that column like that

```
df['column name'] = df['column name'].fillna(0)
avg = df["column name"].mean()
```

But loading 20 million records in pandas may takes some time to execute.

So next I can suggest is use try except which will not break your code where it gets no numbers.

```
for row in c.fetchmany(50):
    try:
        new_var = int(row[0])
        print ("test", type(new_var))
    except:
        pass
```